# Getting error from WCF when trying to consume it from SOAP UI

Tags: wcf, service, protocols, soapui

I have created SOAP UI project and given it the wsdl file location of my service.

Then have added mock response. Now clicked on start option.

I then get bellow error-

```
Exception occured during invocation of channel service 'MyServiceName'.
System.ServiceModel.ProtocolException: The content type text/html; charset=iso-8859-1 of the response message does not match the content type of the binding (text/xml; charset=utf-8). If using a custom encoder, be sure that the IsContentTypeSupported method is implemented properly. The first 175 bytes of the response were: '<html><body><p>There are currently 1 running soapUI MockServices</p><ul><li><a href="/mockbdSVC0254SoapHttp?WSDL">bdSVC0254SoapHttp MockService</a></li></ul></p></body></html>'.
```

Comment: How exactly do you host a web service in SOAP UI?

Comment: I have simply created SOAP UI project and given wsdl file location of my service. Then have added mock response. Now clicked on start option .

Comment: So you are not "hosting" the service on soap ui. You are trying to consume it. I have fixed your question.

Comment: Have a look at this http://www.marcusoft.net/2010/03/soapui-and-testing-wcf-services-how-i.html

Comment: Any solution about this

Answer (score 0):

In case anyone else comes across this like I did when I had this problem, the issue in my case was the endpoint URL of the client wasn't matching the address of the mock in my web.config file.

Before:

[image: Before]

After:

[image: After]